# Android Firestick stock remote mouse

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app for the fire tv stick similar to the app call Mouse Toggle for the fire stick tv.

The app is supposed to take over control of the stock remote and make it into a cursor that is controlled via that stock remotes directional pad.I am emulating a mouse overlay by using a transparent activity and then calling a service and viewgroup that renders the drawn mouse cursor on the screen. Example here:http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-overlay-cursor/

One of my main issues is that when streaming a movie or video and having my 'invisible' app in focus/ in the foreground, the video will stop playing because the app playing the media is not in the foreground. The whole point of the fire stick is to watch video!

My questions are, do you think this is the best way to go about making a mouse cursor that accepts the movement commands from the stock fire stick tv remote and if not, what is another potential way to get button presses from the remote and use it to draw a cursor and then be able to click.

I have tried other ways of emulating a mouse by trying to request focus on the viewgroup 
and taking in onKeyDown events. I have also tried connecting/trying to get the data stream of the
bluetooth firestick remote (Didn't work). The invisible app was my best attempt so far. My next idea is to see if, 
since android runs a psuedo "linux" machine, that I can get access to the remotes inputs, although
I doubt this will work because of the fact that it would be a huge security risk to allow an app to 
view internal files like that.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Android has mouse support, i dont think you can fix the foreground problem if you go that way, you should use a proper mouse for this.

Comment: @Ms.Nehal Thank you and I tried to edit the post by adding on more information.

Comment: @Nanoc I think you may be right about the foreground issue. I could use a new mouse but I am really trying to see if there is a way to "override" the stock remote and use it to act as a mouse instead